# Getting coordinates on MapView, for Android on Titanium Appaccelerator

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium

I'm trying to get the Latitude/Longitude coordinates of a Titanium MapView (app running on Android).

I have the following code on my index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win">           

        <View id="mapview" ns="Ti.Map" onClick="doClick" onComplete="setRegion"
            animate="true" regionFit="true" userLocation="true"
            onLongpress="lngPress"
            mapType="Ti.Map.STANDARD_TYPE" >

            <Annotation id="mountainView"
              latitude="37.390749" longitude="-122.081651"
              title="Appcelerator Headquarters" subtitle="Mountain View, CA"
              pincolor="Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED"
              leftButton="/images/appcelerator_small.png"
              myid="1"/>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And on my index.js I have following function:

```
 function lngPress(evt) {

    var region = $.mapview.getRegion();
    alert('regionlat' + region.latitude + '&' + region.longitude);
    //alert('LongPress' + lat + '&' + lon);
}


$.mapview.annotations = [$.mountainView];
$.mapview.region = {latitude:37.390749, longitude:-122.081651, latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01};
```

This works fine if I don't move the position of the map (just when the program start). However if I move the map to a different location the variable region is not updated. It is always the same (latitude:37.390749, longitude:-122.081651)

**How can I get the updated coordinates?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!

The value is apparently not mean't to change everytime you move across the map. You can create a method to update these variables with the following method:

```
function rgnChanged(evt)
{
    //alert('map moved');
    Ti.App.currentLat = evt.latitude;
    Ti.App.currentLon = evt.longitude;
}
```

Here Ti.App.currentXXX are global variables defined as:

```
Ti.App.currentLat = 20;
Ti.App.currentLon = 10;
```

On the top of the .js file. Also you need to tell the map to call the function rgnChanged, the new index.xml is this (ripping non important parts):

> ```
>   <View id="mapview" ns="Ti.Map" onClick="doClick" onComplete="setRegion"
>       animate="true" regionFit="true" userLocation="true"
>       onLongpress="lngPress" onRegionChanged="rgnChanged"
>       mapType="Ti.Map.STANDARD_TYPE" >
>
>       <Annotation id="mountainView"
>         latitude="37.390749" longitude="-122.081651"
>         title="Appcelerator Headquarters" subtitle="Mountain View, CA"
>         pincolor="Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED"
>         leftButton="/images/appcelerator_small.png"
>         myid="1"/>
>   </View>
> ```

Note the onRegionChanged="rgnChanged" line.